# Captcha component reading session error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using Captcha component from the http://www.devarticles.in/

I have imported captcha component like

```
    App::import('Component', 'Captcha'); //load it
    $this->Captcha = new CaptchaComponent(new ComponentCollection()); //make instance
    $this->Captcha->startup($this);
```

but When I try to call function as

```
    $captcha = $this->Captcha->getVerCode();
```

It gives me error as

```
Call to a member function read() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\westudy_old\app\Controller\Component\CaptchaComponent.php on line 65
```

My function of component is

```
function getVerCode() {
    return $this->Controller->Session->read('security_code');
}
```

and startup function of component is

```
    function startup() {
    $this->Controller = $this->_controller;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare $Controller at top: `public $Controller;`

And change startup() to

`function startup($controller) {`

`$this->Controller = $controller;`

`}`

Normally i am assigning the $controller in the initialize() method. I am not sure if it will work in the startup() method, but i assume it will.

See [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) Components section for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using it in CakePHP 2.x. Latest working version of this captcha component for CakePHP 2.x is available at author's website here http://www.devarticles.in/cakephp/simple-captcha-component-for-cakephp/